# Designing a prototype pcb in Eagle with other parts imported?

Tags: schematics, eaglecad, prototyping

I am protyping a project with several boards like microcontroller, charger, booster etc. for my bachelor's degree in electrical engineering. Now I want to switch from my prototype board and etch my own pcb. I already know how to etch the pcb but I'm not sure how to approach the Eagle schematics.

[image]

I want to have every single board (charger, booster, microcontroller etc.) to be able to plug in to my pcb so I can just unplug them whenever I want. Is it then better to just create a new board and plug in the measurements of each board manually or would it be best to import the seperate boards?

I have the board -eagle files from Adafruit https://www.adafruit.com/product/259, https://www.adafruit.com/product/1903 and I am thinking that I could import them and make my prototype pcb from this but it seems difficult. What would be the best approach here?

Comment: All you really need are the footprints in Eagle, you don't need the entire board schematic.

Comment: You really, really don't want to re-fabricate that BGA package MCU board to merge it in.    Just place compatible headers.  Also you probably don't want to hand etch this - headers are a royal pain on boards without plated through holes unless you can get all the connectivity on the solder side and even then they are prone to lifting pads if mechanically stressed by plugging in something large.  Designing a PCB through to a traditional production house is likely better education, or just point-to-point wire it.

Comment: [This post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182867/how-do-i-add-the-board-of-a-pre-existing-controller-to-my-project, "How do I add the board of a pre-existing controller to my project?") may answer your question.

Comment: @RonBeyer Can I export the footprint from the files and import them?

Comment: @ChrisStratton So it seems better to just use compatible headers then! I was planning on hand etching it for a check that it actually works and then send it to production.

Comment: You can, but the process is pretty involved, the easier thing to do is to make a new part with the appropriate footprint/headers. Really though you don't even need that, you can use standard headers from the parts library and make sure that the right nets go to the right pins. They look to be standard 0.1" headers.

Comment: For anything that will line up with that proto board, just set your grid to 100 mills and drop generic 100 mill headers (or grid to 50 if you have some even count footprints with a centered origin - though I might keep 100 and bring up the menu to type in coordinates for those).

Comment: Thank you both for the input, I now have a clear pathway on what to do next.